# Creating a list with n integers followed by an integer

Tags: python

I need to create a list with n indices of 1 followed by a 10 all in a single line of code (it has to be submitted online on a single line). I tried: `(n*[1]).append(10)` but that returns a None type. Is this doable? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python methods that cause side-effects (read: mutate the object) often evaluate to `None` - which is to reinforce the fact that they exist to cause such side-effects (read: object mutations). `list.append` is one such example of this pattern (although another good example is `list.sort` vs `sorted`).

Compare the usage in the question with:

```
l = n * [1]
l.append(10)   # returns None ..
print l        # .. but list was mutated
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why OP got `None`.  We need more of this on SO, instead of giving other solutions

Comment: @Haidro Thanks! I think it's important to find/explore a combination between the two, but didn't want to repeat the other answers :D

Comment: Sometimes I come to answer, and end up learning something. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
n*[1] + [10]
```

Comment: Ahhhh... I way over complicated that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as:

```
[1] * n + [10]
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, use a list comprehension

```
n=10
[1 if i < n else 10 for i in range(n+1)]

#or a map (although depending on python version it may return a generator)
map(lambda x:1 if x < n else 10,range(n+1))
```

Comment: I think this will give a result that has one too few `1`s in it. You'd want `if i < n` and `range(n+1)`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
[1 for _ in range(n)] + [10]
```

Reason I didn't use the `n * [1] + [10]` method is not only because it has been submitted, but also because in the case where the object you want to spread across the list is mutable; so for example you want to create a list of `n` lists. If you use the `n * [1] + [10]` method, each list in the list will refer to the same list. So when you operate on just one of the lists, all the other lists are affected as well.

**Example**

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[]] * 10
>>> list_of_lists[0].append(9)
>>> print list_of_lists
```

Output:

```
[[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for why this happens